# how to issue a relative url redirect from nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx

How can a redirect be configured in nginx to respond to a certain url with a relative redirect to a specific path?

The [nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#rewrite-missing-http) suggests that this is the default mode for nginx, but in reality if the location being redirected to starts with a / nginx is responding with an absolute url in the Location field.

For local server configuration containing locations:

```
location = /a {
  return 301 some/path;
}
location = /b {
  return 301 /qwerty;
}
```

the response Location to a request to /a is:

```
Location: some/path
```

and for /b it is:

```
Location: http://127.0.0.1/qwerty
```

however, we would like /b to respond with:

```
Location: /qwerty
```

The reason we would like to use relative redirects is that we would like to access nginx from different domains and proxies, e.g. in clear in dev or via ssl-terminating load-balancer, and would rather keep things simple by relieving nginx of needing to understand that context.

FYI these examples were tested against nginx versions 1.4.6 and 1.9.6, using curl e.g.:

```
curl --head http://127.0.0.1/b
```

Answer (score 31):

There is an nginx directive [`absolute_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#absolute_redirect) available from nginx version **1.11.8**, which is enabled by default. If **disabled**, redirects issued by nginx will be relative. This issue is a bit older, but maybe useful for all of you hitting it from google.

```
 absolute_redirect off;
```

Comment: This is simplest and perfect solution, but I had to check it in a private browser window to confirm that Location header is relative. Regular browser window still shows the absolute Location header due to caching behaviour.

Answer (score 24):

nginx header filter always inserts `<scheme>://<host>` if `return` uri starts with `/`.
(see `ngx_http_script_return_code()` and `ngx_http_header_filter()` function in nginx source for reference)

---

So, if client (e.g. google chrome) can accept `Location:  /qwerty`, you can use the following configure:

```
location = /b {
    return 301 " /qwerty";    # insert space char before "/qwerty"
}
```

---

Another solution can generate `Location: /qwerty` exactly, via [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) and [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) directive:

```
location = /b {
    add_header Location "/qwerty";
    content_by_lua 'ngx.exit(301)';
}
```

How does this weird configure work?

- use `ngx.exit` to exit with status code with 301, it does not create "Location" header (`return` directive always create "Location" header, even empty header value)
- use `add_header` to add `Location: /qwerty` header, it does not insert `<scheme>://<host>`

Comment: Nice trick with a space in "return" directive. Is this behavior of nginx documented anywhere?

Comment: That space trick is hilarious and awesome, how did you discover it?

Comment: hi @TrevorFreeman , RFC 2616 allows "space trick" actually. In chapter "4.2 Message Headers", the header value is defined as `field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )`. `*LWS` means zero or many `linear white space`.

Comment: @xiaochen RFC 2616 is obsolete for 3 years. RFC 7231 now allows relative redirects https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231

Comment: add_header solution is significantly slower