# Nginx redirect without scheme and hostname

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, header, location

I have used return or rewrite in Nginx to redirect, but both will redirect with the http header Location which has value of the full url, but I want it just value the path.

for example:

> return 301 /test;

or

> rewrite ^/$ /test permanent;

will has the Location value of
http://www.example.com/test

but I want it be just
/test

I wonder if it is possible.

---

Solved.
as of 1.11.8, just set the directive(Thanks to @RichardSmith):

> absolute_redirect off;

before 1.11.8, I find a wonderful answer(Thanks to @xiaochen):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462409

Comment: Have you tried `absolute_redirect off;`?

Comment: @richard-smith Thanks a lot. I try it on my local computer with Nginx 1.12.0, and it work just fine. but for the server with Nginx 1.10.1, it's an unknown directive. And I checkout the documentation and find out it's introduced in 1.11.8. Maybe I have to upgrade Nginx on server to solve this problem, but I still look forward to compatible solution for older Nginx.